# Dynamic UIWebView Link

Tags: xcode, ios6

So normally to load a UIWebView I do..

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [_webView loadRequest:request];
```

However, now I need to do this dynamically, depending on a table cell that a user clicks.  I load the table cells from JSON and everything works fine. Now I need to get the "id" of the post in the cell, and load it dynamically.  Currently I've tried this but it doesn't work...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/story.php?id="];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:storyId relativeToURL:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just format the URL string?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
            stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/story.php?id=%@", storyId]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: When I do this, the UIWebView doesn't load any web page.  I don't even get a 404 error.  Just a white page

Comment: What happens if you paste the same URL into Safari? Does it load anything? Validate that your URL works in a standard browser before testing it in your code.